# Values are not showing in 2048?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating div with tile class using js and and elements tab is also showing those div are getting created but are on not displayed, I tried changing `z-index` value but that did nothing
[values not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT4fC.png)

But when I'm adding tile div manually it is showing up, but if I add more than one div manually they are just showing in the same tile[Values showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M4Ts.png)

Sorry I don't know how to add three different js files in snippets, so you can check the repo here [Repo Link](https://github.com/Coditdoc/2048)

Note - @G-Cyrillus edited the snippet now its working thanks(values issue not resolved yet).

```js
// https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Coditdoc/2048/24934e6037c41b897ba8a615c5cb07e154b87b1f/Grid.js
const GRID_SIZE = 4;
const CELL_SIZE = 20;
const CELL_GAP = 2;


//export default 
class Grid {
    //making cells private is so that it can be only accesible in grid class
    #cells
    constructor(gridElement) {
        gridElement.style.setProperty("--grid-size",GRID_SIZE)
        gridElement.style.setProperty("--cell-size", `${CELL_SIZE}vmin`)
        gridElement.style.setProperty("--cell-gap", `${CELL_GAP}vmin`)
        this.#cells = createCellElements(gridElement).map((cellElement, index) => {
            return new Cell(cellElement, index % GRID_SIZE, Math.floor(index / GRID_SIZE))
        })

    }

    get #emptyCells() {
        return this.#cells.filter(cell => cell.tile == null)
    }
    // it will return which ever cell is empty
    randomEmptyCell() {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.#emptyCells.length)
        return this.#emptyCells[randomIndex]
    }
}
class Cell {
   #cellElement
   #x
   #y
   #tile

    constructor(cellElement, x,y) {
        this.#cellElement = cellElement
        this.#x = x
        this.#y = y
    }
    get tile() {
        return this.#tile
    }
    
    set tile(value) {
        this.#tile = value
        if(value == null) return
        this.#tile.x = this.#x
        this.#tile.y = this.#y
    }
}

function createCellElements(gridElement) {
    const cells = []
    for(let i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE * GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        const cell = document.createElement("div")
        cell.classList.add("cell")
        cells.push(cell)
        gridElement.append(cell)
    }

    return cells
}

//https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Coditdoc/2048/24934e6037c41b897ba8a615c5cb07e154b87b1f/Tile.js

//export default 
class Tile {
    #tileElement
    #x
    #y
    #value
    // randomly set 2 or 4 
    constructor(tileContainer, value = Math.random() > .5 ? 2 : 4) {
        this.#tileElement = document.createElement("div")
        this.#tileElement.classList.add("tile")
        tileContainer.append(this.#tileElement)
        this.vaule = value
    }

    set value(v) {
        this.#value = v
        this.#tileElement.textContent = v
        const power = Math.log2(v)
    }
    
    set x(value) {
        this.#x = value
        this.#tileElement.style.setProperty("--x", value)
    }

    set y(value) {
        this.#y = value
        this.#tileElement.style.setProperty("--y", value)
    }
}

//https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Coditdoc/2048/24934e6037c41b897ba8a615c5cb07e154b87b1f/brain.js

//import Grid from "./Grid.js";
//import Tile from "./Tile.js";

const board = document.getElementById("holder");

const grid = new Grid(board) 
 grid.randomEmptyCell().tile = new Tile(board)
 grid.randomEmptyCell().tile = new Tile(board)
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 7.5vmin;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#holder{
    display: grid;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-size), var(--cell-size));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-size), var(--cell-size));
    gap: var(--cell-gap);
    padding: var(--cell-gap);
}

.cell {
    background-color: #aaa;
    border-radius: 1vmin;
}

.tile {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: var(--cell-size);
    height: var(--cell-size);
    background-color: hsl(200, 50%, var(--background-lightness));
    color: hsl(200, 25%, var(--text-lightness));
    border-radius: 1vmin;
    top: calc(var(--y) * (var(--cell-size) + var(--cell-gap)) + var(--cell-gap));
    left: calc(var(--x) * (var(--cell-size) + var(--cell-gap)) + var(--cell-gap));
    font-weight: bold;
    animation: wow 220ms ease-in-out;
    transition: 100ms ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes wow {
    0% {
        opacity: .5;
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>2048</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css">
    <script src="brain.js" type="module"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="holder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your example here is not going to work since you can not link to github files in a script tag.

Comment: What can I do please suggest something

Comment: just edited your snippet, it looks working. Welcome on SO! added the raw link to your scripts as comments and removed import/export

Comment: There are different (external) online coding-sandboxes you could use (jsfiddle for example). You can just link it in your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok finally after spending 2 whole days I finally figured out the issue

```
constructor(tileContainer, value = Math.random() > .5 ? 2 : 4) {
    this.#tileElement = document.createElement("div")
    this.#tileElement.classList.add("tile")
    tileContainer.append(this.#tileElement)
    this.vaule = value
}
```

If you look closely you will see the error in last line `this.vaule`
a simple spelling mistake.

I don't know why console didn't show any error.